# How should I assign a sequence number (rank (?)) based on item type?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I am trying to analyze item sequence and its average duration for each item usage.
To give you an example and my intended output, please refer to the table below.

[image]

As you can see in the table, I want to assign an item sequence number (red text) next to the amount column.
For this task, what I only care is the the sequence of the item.
I have a vague understanding of either using lead() function or row number() over (partition by ...) code.

However, all codes that I have tried so far hasn't provided the intended result.

Please help,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is "*the sequence of the item*" defined by sorting on the `item` column?

Comment: Thank you very much. this was my first time using stack overflow. yes, sequence of the item was defined by sorting on the item.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can achieve this with `dense_rank()`

```
select id, 
       start_date, 
       end_date, 
       item, 
       amount, 
       dense_rank() over (order by item) as item_sequence
from the_table
order by item;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Your query worked for my task!!